# How to restrict a Lambda function to respond only to specific origins?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I want to restrict my Lambda function (created with the Serverless Framework tool) to accept requests only from `abc.com` and `def.com`. It should reject all other requests. How can I do this? I tried setting access control origins like this:

```
cors: true
response:
  headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'beta.leafycode.com leafycode.com'"
```

and like this in the handler:

```
headers: {
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "beta.leafycode.com leafycode.com"
},
```

but nothing worked. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` [doesn't accept multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains).

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1850482/1476885):

> Sounds like the recommended way to do it is to have your server read
>   the Origin header from the client, compare that to the list of domains
>   you'd like to allow, and if it matches, echo the value of the Origin
>   header back to the client as the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in
>   the response.

So, when writing support to the OPTIONS verb, which is the verb where the browser will preflight a request to see if CORS is supported, you need to write your Lambda code to inspect the `event` object to see the domain of the client and dynamically set the corresponding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with the domain.

In your question, you have used a CORS configuration for two different types: Lambda and Lamba-Proxy. I recommend that you use the second option, so you will be able to set the domain dynamically.

```
headers: {
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : myDomainValue
},
```

See more about CORS configuration in the Serverless Framework [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/).

Comment: Hi, I just tried with one domain and sill it's not restricting the requests.

Comment: @THpubs, if you are setting the headers in the handler, as I have suggested, make sure that you **don't** have the option `integration: lambda` in your `serverless.yml` file. If it still doesn't work, I suggest that you create a new hello-world project to test just this feature, so we may eliminate another misconfiguration.

Comment: Great thanks it worked! Removing the integration fixed the issue.